# extJS - Call a function from another function within the same controller

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs4.2, sencha-architect

Super-stupid question, but I can't make it work, how do we call a function from another function within the same `Controller`? I use sencha architect.

Here is my controller where I a have a listener and a function, I want to call `generateField` function from the listener

```
Ext.define('Medlemssystem.controller.MemberOrganisationController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    views: [
        'LocalOrgPanel'
    ],

    onLocalOrganisationInfoAfterRender: function(component, eOpts) {

        main_id = component.up('#memberTab').main_id;

        component.removeAll();

        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'OrganizationCustomFieldServlet',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            params: {
                "operation" : "get",
                "org_id" : main_id 
            },
            success: function(response) {
                var result = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                result.forEach(function(n) {
                    component.add(generateField(n.customField.name));
                });
            },
            failure: function() {
                console.log('woops');
            }
        });
    },

    generateField: function(name, type, id, required, description) {
        var field = Ext.create("Ext.form.field.Text", {fieldLabel:name});

        return field;
    },

    init: function(application) {
        this.control({
            "LocalOrgPanel": {
                afterrender: this.onLocalOrganisationInfoAfterRender
            }
        });
    }

});
```

when I call `component.add(generateField(n.customField.name));` I get "function not found" error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `onLocalOrganisationInfoAfterRender: function(component, eOpts) {`

paste `var that = this;`

And then `component.add(that.generateField(n.customField.name));`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way is to set scope for the ajax request call back.

Like this

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'OrganizationCustomFieldServlet',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        params: {
            "operation" : "get",
            "org_id" : main_id 
        },
        success: function(response) {
           console.log(this); //<-- scope here is Window by default, unless scope is set below
        },
        failure: function() {
            console.log('woops');
        },
        scope :this //<--   Sets the controller as the scope for the success call back

    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This is also a correct answer, but I will accept sine's answer since he posted it earlier :-)